# Replace variable in read JSON data in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I read a JSON data from file in shell script using `jq`.

```
{"sample": {
  ...
  "timestamp": "$NOW",
  ...
}
}
```

SAMPLE_DATA = `jq '.' sample.json`

I want to change the field `timestamp:$NOW` with the following variable value inside shell script.

`NOW=$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ)`

How do I achieve it?

Comment: I have edited to make it valid.

Comment: Good. Have you tried anything?